# Misalignment on Canvas Scripting API

Tags: javascript, canvas, scripting, html5-canvas, grid

I've just started working on a snake game in JavaScript using the Canvas Scripting API and have run into a problem that I can't figure out how to solve

I'm trying to generate the food for the snake on any one place in the grid. However, the snake itself does not align correctly with the fruit.

The code i'm using to generate the fruit is

```
let fruitPosX = Math.round(Math.random() * canvas.width)
let fruitPosY = Math.round(Math.random() * canvas.height)
```

Here's an example
[image: Snake being incorrectly aligned with the fruit]

How am I supposed to fix this, I'm guessing some kind of grid system but how would I go about doing so? Also, if anyone has a different approach please post it below.

Comment: share your code and provide a minimum reproducible example

Comment: I've shared it now :)

Answer (score 0):

Assumign width of the snake is `snakeWidth`, you must also have `fruitWidth` and `fruitHeight` to be equal to the `snakeWidth`

```
let canvasWidth = canvas.width;
let canvasHeight = canvas.height;
let cols = canvasWidth/snakeWidth; // create the exact number of "aligned" columns your fruits can occupy
let rows = canvasHeight/snakeWidth; // create the exact number of "aligned" rows when the snake moves horizontally

let fruitPosX = Math.round(Math.random() * cols) * snakeWidth; // find a random column to place the fruit
let fruitPosY = Math.round(Math.random() * rows) * snakeWidth; // find a random row to place the fruit
```